# Multiple Http requests and responses using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection, bots

I am developing a very simple http bot. I am using the `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` class and I have to make multiple requests.
Snippet of code :

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection =
    (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url+"?"+firstParameters).openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
headerFields = urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
keys = headerFields.keySet();
for(String key : keys){
    if(key != null && key.contains("ookie")){
        cookies = urlConnection.getHeaderField(key);
        break;
    }
}
for(String cookie : cookies.split(";")){
    if(cookie.contains("JSESSION")){
        JSESSION = cookie.split("=")[1];
        break;
    }
}
document = new InputSource(urlConnection.getInputStream());
parser.setDocument(document);
attributesId.put("name",new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(attributesNames)));
elementsIds.put("INPUT",attributesId);
elements = parser.getValues(elementsIds);
for(String attr : attributesNames){
    secondParameters = secondParameters.replaceAll("#r"+index,elements.get(attr));
}
urlConnection.getInputStream().close();
//Second call 
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url2).openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID="+JSESSION);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
payload = new PrintWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
payload.print(secondParameters);
payload.flush();
payload.close();
```

Summarizing the code above, first i do a request without any payload and i am able to see the correct response from the server, but the problem is when i make the second request (now with payload and with the JSESSION cookie), what i receive it his the same response that i received in the first request, it looks like i am making the first request again.
So my question is , what i am doing wrong ?
I just need to open one connection, and then change the headers and payload ?
There is any tutorial related with multiple http requests(with mixed methods , post and get)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've never used `HttpURLConnection` before.  I usually use [Apache's HTTPClient code](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html).  There are a lot of docs and tutorials about it on their home page.

Couple of things that I noticed about your code:

- You code does not handle multiple `Cookie` headers on the response.  Mine seems to handle that better.
- Are you sure that all you need is `JSESSION`?  Maybe there are other cookies you are missing?
- Have you debugged your code to make sure that your `JSESSION` cookie gets set appropriately?  I added some `trim()` calls in my cookie processing code to make sure some spaces didn't slip in there.
- I can't see the real value of your `secondParameters`.  I have no idea if they are valid.    Have you debugged your code to verify the `secondParamters` value looks good.  You can see in my code what I'm posting to the server.  Btw, I'd use a `StringBuilder` instead of `+` to build them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one more question. I you do see what you are posting to the server ? For example , i can use fiddler or firebug to see the traffic between browser and server.What do you use to see what is being send from your java program ?

Comment: I don't have a good answer @tt0686.  I'd use firebug as well or maybe a proxy server.  I don't see any easy way to do that using `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: This might have been usefull to others, maybe, The code snipped was hosted on temporary site, which is gone,  making this answer completely useless instead.